# Converting string list to Int[]

Tags: java, android

In my code I'm splitting a string and then adding them to a string like this one:

```
List<String> stringX = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But in the next part I need to retrieve the string and convert it to an int[]. How would I go about this or is there a better way using the code I already have?

I've tried converting the code a few different ways but end up getting these exceptions: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and NumberFormatException.

```
List<String> stringX = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> stringY = new ArrayList<String>();

public void convertString() {
    String input = getString(R.string.inputString);
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(input);

    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        list.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
    }
    for (String str : list) {
        String formatted = (str.replace(", ", ","));
        formattedList.add(formatted);
    }

    String[] values = formattedList.toArray(new String[formattedList.size()]);

    for (String s : values) {
        String coordXY[] = s.split(",");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(coordXY[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(coordXY[1]);
        stringX.add(Integer.toString(x));
        stringY.add(Integer.toString(y));
    }
    difference();
}


private void difference(){
    // Setting the input array. These are what I need to get from the string lists
    int inputX[] = { 0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4 };
    int inputY[]= { 0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1 };

    // Obtaining the number of records
    int noOfRecordsX = inputX.length;
    int noOfRecordsY = inputY.length;

    // Array for storing differences
    int[] differenceX = new int [noOfRecordsX];
    int[] differenceY = new int [noOfRecordsY];

    differenceX [0] = 0; // First record difference is 0 only
    differenceY [0] = 0; // First record difference is 0 only

    // Looping number of records times
    for( int i=0; i < noOfRecordsX -1 ;i++)
    {
        // Difference = next record - current record
        differenceX [i+1]= inputX [i+1] - inputX[i];
    }

    for( int i=0; i < noOfRecordsY -1 ;i++)
    {
        // Difference = next record - current record
        differenceY [i+1]= inputY [i+1] - inputY[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way you would get a `NumberFormatException` is if the thing you try to parse to an `int` isn't an `int`. You should learn to use your debugger.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I did and it was because of the commas in the int. So i removed them and then got the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. This one was a lot less clear as to what I needed to do to fix it.

Comment: On **which** line... look at your stack trace. It will tell you exactly which line is throwing the exception. And if you examine that line with your debugger all should become clear.

Comment: Also for the numberFormatExcetion it should tell you what token could not be parsed. Please add this to your post as well

Comment: @Elliott Frisch I had removed that code as it isn't working.

Comment: @Barns In convertString() i'm converting this string `(0, 0) (1, 3) (4, 4) (4, 2) (4, 2) (0, 1) (3, 2) (2, 3) (4, 1)` into `stringX: 0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 0, 3, 2, 4` and `stringY:  0, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1`.

From here I then need to work out the difference from next number - current number and loop it. That's what I'm doing in `difference()` but I have the values hard coded in. This is the issue I'm having is going from the outcome of `convertString()` to `difference()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void testMethod(){
    String input = "(0, 0) (1, 3) (4, 4) (4, 2) (4, 2) (0, 1) (3, 2) (2, 3) (4, 1)";
    ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String[] sa = matcher.group(1).split(",");
        x.add(Integer.valueOf(sa[0].trim()));
        y.add(Integer.valueOf(sa[1].trim()));
    }
}
```

Hope you don't mind that I used an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of `int[]`.


I'm sure there are some top RegEx specialists out there who could do this all in two lines, but this will do--and it is easy to follow what is being done.

Comment: Thanks for that Barns. It shortened my function and really helped me out. I now have everything working as it should!

Comment: @Jordan :: I solved a problem yesterday for AngryCubeDev... Looked at his [Tweeter feed](https://twitter.com/AngryCubeDev) and saw a tweet about Chainsaw Coffee Roasters. Now I see in your profile that you are a dev at  Chainsaw Coffee Roasters. You guys know each other?